# I have installed TestNG Plugin in my eclipse (Version 4.28) but not able to see the "TestNG" in add Libraries

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, testng, testng-eclipse, testng.xml

I have installed TestNG Plugin in my eclipse (Version 4.28.0) but not able to see the "TestNG" in add Libraries. Many times, I have uninstalled and reinstalled but still not able to see "TestNG" Option under (Java build path -> Libraries -> add Libraries)

I have download TestNG Plugin from client confluence page and installed it through Install new software and I have added required dependencies in my pom.xml file for my maven project in my eclipse (Version 4.28.0) but not able to see the "TestNG" in add Libraries. Many times, I have uninstalled and reinstalled but still not able to see "TestNG" Option under (Java build path -> Libraries -> add Libraries)

Comment: The TestNG plugin adds TestNG support to the IDE, it does not add the TestNG dependency/library to your project. What kind of project do you have (plain Java, Maven, Gradle, ... project?)? Which tutorial or documentation do you follow?